# AngularJS variable accessible from the whole code

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, global-variables

as you can see I have opened .xml file and parsed it to a xmlDoc. What I am trying to achieve is that this xmlDoc will be accessible from the whole script(I want to make some functions later which will be displaying elements from .xml to a screen). I searched the web and find that it is possible via global variable $rootScope but couldn't implement it correctly. I hope you guys can help me. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <p id="title">asd</p>
    <button name="opt1" ng-click="">YES</button>
    <button name="opt2" ng-click="">NO</button>

<script>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
var parser, xmlDoc;
app.run(function($rootScope, $http) {
    text = $http.get("file.xml").then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
    }).then(function(text) {
        parser = new DOMParser();
        xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");
        document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = 
        xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways in angular to declare and use a global variable.
examples:
1. By using $rootScope.
   we need to add a dependency in our controller or service like:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', function($rootScope, $scope){
      $rootScope.yourVar = 'YourValue';
      ....
      ....
   }]);

and then You can use this `yourVar` variable anywhere in your code.
```

Another way is by using `angular factory or servive`.

```
app.factory('factoryObj', ['$scope', function($scope){
    let factoryObj.yourVar = 'yourValue';

    return factoryObj;
 }]);
```

Now in any controller or any other service, by using this `factoryObj` as a dependency and then inside that controller or service we can use `factoryObj.yourVar` as a variable. as:

```
app.controller('myCtrl',['$rootScope','$scope','factoryObj'function($rootScope,$scope, factoryObj){

  console.log('factoryObj.yourVar value: ',factoryObj.yourVar);

}]);
```